# Is the HDD inside the sky+ HD box 2.5" or 3.5?

Tags: hard-drive

We recently changed our Sky+ HD box in our household and I wand to use the old hard drive using a SATA to USB converter. The only thing is I don't know what the size is (2.5" or 3.5") (haven't taken it out yet).

Thanks.

Comment: connectivity to the harddrive is the same for a 2,5" and 3,5" drive. So the size of the drive really is irrellevant for connecting it. But it may be relevant for your computer. In that case, you can get a 2,5" to 3,5" convertor bracket.

Comment: I think the previous answer is for the case where you want to connect your drive inside a computer. But you mentioned USB, so that sounds like an external box. If it's a box, you actually need to know the size to get a good fit. There are other options though, like open "bays" where you can attach the disk. Many of these are compatible with both sizes.